# Psychology behind dumb child doing good in academics

Tags: abnormal-psychology, educational-psychology

This is my first question in this forum and hence forgive me if the question is amateurish. I was always interested in what a psychology expert will say about this.

Consider a boy who is dumb from his childhood. Here dumbness means, he is terrible at making decisions in the immediate situations. Very shy from childhood. Sometimes people make fun indirectly, and he does not get that at that moment. Sometimes other persons try to draw information from him which may harm him, and he innocently tells everything ... etc.

But on the other hand, that same boy turned out to be good in school. Good at the undergraduate level and doing well even in postgraduation also.

This leads me to the question, why do some boys turn out to be so dumb? It seems like it is genetic rather upbringing problem. I will appreciate a deeper and literature based answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people confuse shyness with introversion, and the difference is that shy people do it out of *fear*, while introverted people do it out of the urge to be *alone*.

Being shy is a bad thing.

Being an introvert is NOT a bad thing.

People also confuse *Dumbness* with *Gullibility*.

Gullibility is a failure of ***social*** intelligence, which is again a clear sign of high introversion, and they do that because they're a better judge of character.

Simply put "Intelligent people are more likely to trust others, while those who score lower on measures of intelligence are less likely to do so"

*I couldn't do better than this.*

source:

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2014/03/140316133840.htm